# "Unexpected element <reciever> found in <manifest><application>" in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver, manifest

I tried to add a BroadcastReciever to the Android part of my Xamarin app to help with notifications, but if I try to register it in the manifest, I get the build error in the title of this question. I don't want to use code attributes because then it won't work if the app isn't running according to Microsoft's documentation (I don't remember which page).

Here is my (unmerged) manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.partylist" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="Partylist.Android">
        <reciever android:name=".AlarmReciever" android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </reciever>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECIEVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
</manifest>
```

Also, the line that the error says it's on is actually the line where I have the intent filter inside the BroadcastReciever, not the BroadcastReciever itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out for spelling typos, It should be `<receiver>` from `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: That was the problem.